How to Avoid Duplicating Validation Logic in EF Core configuration and Value Objects?
I'm working on designing the configuration of my entities using EF Core. Currently, I keep my validation logic inside the entities and value objects. However, I'm looking for a way to share this knowledge with ef configuration without duplication and violation of DDD.
public sealed record Name : ValueObject
{
    public string Value { get; }

    private Name(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static Result<Name> Create(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            return Result.Failure<Name>(UserErrors.NameIsNullOrEmpty());
        }

        string name = input.Trim();

        if (name.Length < 1 || name.Length > 50)
        {
            return Result.Failure<Name>(UserErrors.NameLengthOutOfRange(1, 50));
        }

        if (!char.IsUpper(name[0]))
        {
            return Result.Failure<Name>(UserErrors.NameMustStartWithUppercase());
        }

        return new Name(name);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}

Example of configuration:
builder.ComplexProperty(u => u.FirstName, firstName =>
{
    firstName
        .Property(f => f.Value)
        .HasColumnName("FirstName")
        .HasMaxLength(50) // DUBLICATION HERE.
        .IsRequired();
});

My initial idea was to open properties inside Entities/Value Objects related to validation , but I am not sure that it is the best approach. Thank you.

One way could be to store your limits (like the number 50) in constant fields and use them in different locations. In that case if you change MaxNameLength it will be applied everywhere it was used.

@Parsa99 thank you, I will stay with that approach
